# How to set a cancel button in Progress Dialog?

Tags: android

I want to set a cancel button in my `ProgressDialog`. Below is my code:

```
myDialog = new ProgressDialog(BaseScreen.this);
myDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
myDialog.show();
```

I want to set a button with an `onClickListener` on this `ProgressDialog`.
I tried with this code:

```
myDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        myDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

But it isn't working. I tried other similar listeners also, but still no success.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The `setButton` method you are using is deprecated (although it should still work). Also, you might want to add the button **before** showing the dialog. Try:

```
myDialog = new ProgressDialog(BaseScreen.this);
myDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        myDialog.dismiss();//dismiss dialog
    }
});
myDialog.show();
```

Comment: FYI, `dialog.dismiss()` is not necessary in the `onClick` listener as it will automatically dismiss the dialog. In fact, this method does not allow you to prevent the dialog from being dismissed.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579030/prevent-progressdialog-from-getting-dismissed-by-onclick) link if need to prevent automatic dismissal of the dialog when negative button is clicked.

Comment: Use context.getString(android.R.string.cancel) instead "Cancel"

Answer (score 18):

Make sure you call `myDialog.setButton` before calling `myDialog.show();`
 Also you can use `myDialog.setButton("Cancel", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);` if you only need to close the dialog on button click.

Answer (score 3):

check this

```
private void createCancelProgressDialog(String title, String message, String buttonText)
{
    cancelDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    cancelDialog.setTitle(title);
    cancelDialog.setMessage(message);
    cancelDialog.setButton(buttonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // Use either finish() or return() to either close the activity or just the dialog
            return;
        }
    });
    cancelDialog.show();
}
```

then just use a simple call method from elsewhere in your activity

```
createCancelProgressDialog("Loading", "Please wait while activity is loading", "Cancel");
```

Comment: It is cancelled on 4.3 or above