# How to set equal button height in progress dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, progressdialog

I have progress dialog:

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this);
```

with some buttons like this:

```
mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //some code
            }
         });
```

And I'm trying to set their parameters via (and get NullPointerException):

```
Button cancel = mProgressDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
int width1 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension
                (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
         **NullPointerException here:** cancel.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                 (width1, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
```

So, **how can I set buttons' layout parameters** here (without using custom progress dialog)? 
Something tells me that I can't set them at all, instead of using custom progress dialog...

P.S.: sorry if I'm missing something very simple here

Comment: you did'nt set a `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` to your `mProgressDialog`, that's why you get `nullPointerException`

Comment: You are indeed missing something simple. You set the BUTTON_NEUTRAL, and try to get BUTTON_NEGATIVE.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, because I've pasted not all code. I've fixed it, of course I don't have it in my source code. Maybe you can see something else wrong there?

Comment: @Houcine maybe you've noticed something else here?

Comment: @Aswin Kumar maybe you've noticed something else here?

Comment: @janot : the only thing is that you get nullPointerException because you didn't set any BUTTON_NEGATIVE to your mProgressDialog , so when trying the get it , it will return null. of course we are based on the code that you gived above :). otherwise , i didn't notice something else

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037433/how-to-set-cancel-button-in-progress-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are installed to the dialog after Dialog.onCreate(). So you can override this method and add your code here, or you have to get the button after Dialog.show() is invoked.

Here is my sample, i changed the weight of the first button.

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "confirm",
            (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "cancel",
            (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
    dialog.show();
    Button btConfirm = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btConfirm
            .getLayoutParams();
    params.weight = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was my mistake: "you have to get the button **after** Dialog.show() is invoked".

Answer (score 1):

Here the codes for AlertDialog with a builder

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Setup.this);
            builder.setMessage("Message", 1))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.browseonlinesupport), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            })
            .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.submit_help_request), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null) // to make the button even widths
            //.show()
            ;
            //                }
            AlertDialog helpDialog = builder.create();
            helpDialog.show();  // call show() must from dialog not builder, otherwise button not created and getButton is null
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams btParams;
            Button btPositive = helpDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            btParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btPositive.getLayoutParams();
            btParams.weight = 1;
            btParams.width = btParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            Button btNegative = helpDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            btParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btNegative.getLayoutParams();
            btParams.weight = 1;
            btParams.width = btParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            Button btNeutral = helpDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            btParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btNeutral.getLayoutParams();
            btParams.weight = 1;
            btParams.width = btParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

*, call show() must from dialog not builder, otherwise button not created and getButton is null