# how (and when?) to cancel LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate if ever possible?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

There are a lot of questions about LocationManager and different approaches of obtaining the user's position. However, most of them are concentrated on the accuracy and my approach is a bit different because of the different requirements.
What I need is an approx. GPS position of a user but as fast as possible (but only after a user taps a button) and some EditText boxes should be filled with the coordinates. The problem is that in most cases the data transfer will be disabled on the device so the Network Location will not be available. I have to stick with GPS which can't be fast by design. So here's what I do:

On button click I call the getGPS() method of my main Activity and since I don't care about the accuracy (I just need to get an approx. coordinates) I'm checking for the last known location, comments in the code are self-explanatory

```
public void getGPS(View view) {
    // load all available Location providers
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(false);
    // determine the last known location within 2 hours available from cache
    Location myLocation = null;
    Date now = new Date();
    long time = now.getTime();
    long timeDiff = LOCATION_MAX_AGE;
    for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null) {
            long t = l.getTime();
            if (time - t < timeDiff) {
                myLocation = l;
                time = t;
                timeDiff = time - t;
            }
        }
    }
    // if failed to get cached location or if it is older than 2 hours, request GPS position
    if (myLocation == null) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0,
                    new Intent(SINGLE_UPDATE_ACTION),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(SINGLE_UPDATE_ACTION);
            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // when received an answer from the LocationManager
                    Location gpsLocation = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
                    fillLocation(gpsLocation);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received GPS location: " + gpsLocation.getLatitude() + ", " + gpsLocation.getLongitude() + " Time: " + gpsLocation.getTime());
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(pIntent);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                }
            };
            context.registerReceiver(receiver, iFilter);
            // I'm absolutely fine with getting the first available GPS position and that's enough to me.
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, pIntent);
         // if GPS is disabled in settings allow user to enable it
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    } else {
        // if fresh enough lastKnownLocation is found
        fillLocation(myLocation);
    }
}
```

All works very well, in most cases there is a lastKnownLocation and coordinates appear immediately after user taps a button. But when I'm not so lucky, the GPS icon appears and here the problem comes. Since there is no data connection available the GPS fix takes longer than usual. During this time the Activity remains accessible and user is not really aware that the coordinates are about to appear soon. Another problem is when the user is not able to get a GPS fix within a reasonable time he should be able to cancel the request.

So, my question is: what is the best approach here?
More specifically: is it possible (and how?) to show something like a waiting dialog to the user (e.g. "Acquiring GPS position...") and one button "Cancel" which may interrupt the request and bring the user back to main activity, stop any GPS activity and show a toast asking the user to enter the coordinates manually?

Sorry if this is something very easy, I'm just started to learn developing for Android and my app is almost done except this thing. I searched really hard and didn't find anything unfortunately. Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just half an hour after I posted my question I realized that I might already know the answer. I probably need to open a dialog with a waiting cursor to block the UI, show my message and a Cancel button and request LocationManager from there. If a user clicks Cancel before we get a fix then I should unregister my receiver and dismiss the dialog.
Definitely I will try this tomorrow, but any thoughts or suggestions and even comments are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) to inform user that is waiting for the fix. You can set the message and add a `Cancel` button to it as well. See this link: [How to set cancel button in Progress Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037433/how-to-set-cancel-button-in-progress-dialog)

If the user cancel the `ProgressDialod`, then you would start the screen with request for manual input.

Regards.

Comment: Luis, thanks, this is exactly what I had in mind yesterday (see my edit) but I surely accept your answer as it saved me some time with finding the proper name of that dialog class :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Luis answered my secondary question (which is basically "when?" to cancel the request) I will add the answer to my first and main question (easier one though): yes, it is possible to cancel the GPS searching after the requestSingleUpdate method call if you just unregister the listener and remove updates. I do this in onClick method for the Cancel button. One thing to remember as well: call the cancel() method to the ProgressDialog if the GPS got the fix and returned the position.