# How to show AlertDialog without closing ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have a `ProgressDialog` with Cancel `Button`. On click the `Button` I want to show an `AlertDialog`for confirmation. However, when the `AlertDialog` pops up the `ProgressDialog` is closed. I tried calling PD.hide() on click, then AD.dismiss() and PD.show(), for the option of disallowing cancel. Can't retrieve the progress bar. I would also accept showing the `AlertDialog` on top of the `ProgressDialog`, like when you double tap and two `Dialogs` appear one over the other. But that doesn't happen in this case. Hides it automatically. Any thoughts?

```
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        DialogFactory.DialogParams dlgParams = new DialogFactory.DialogParams();
                        dlgParams.setTitle(titleWarning)
                                .setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert))
                                .setContent(context.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_progform_cancel))
                                .setYesButton(true)
                                .setNoButton(true);

                        final Dialog cancelDialog = DialogFactory.getInstance(context).createDialog(dlgParams);
                        cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                cancelDialog.dismiss();
                                progressDialog.cancel();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                postTransferCancelEvent(true);
                            }
                        });
                        cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                progressDialog.show();
                                cancelDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


        progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: post code you have tried...

Comment: Please post relevant code, it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: why you are hiding `progressDialog` I mean  just show your `cancelDialog `, and on `yesButton` cancel both dialog and progress dialog, for `noButton` cancel only dialog

Comment: Because that was the problem, that it hides it anyway when I show the `AlertDialog`. So I started playing with those show/hide/dismiss methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is that any buttons that are set using `setButton()` have a default click behavior that is processed after you custom onClickListener. The default click behavior is to close the dialog.

To get around this, set your click listener *after* showing the dialog.

```
progressDialog.show();

Button cancelButton = progressDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
cancelButton.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_cancel));
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    DialogFactory.DialogParams dlgParams = new DialogFactory.DialogParams();
                    dlgParams.setTitle(titleWarning)
                            .setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert))
                            .setContent(context.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_progform_cancel))
                            .setYesButton(true)
                            .setNoButton(true);

                    final Dialog cancelDialog = DialogFactory.getInstance(context).createDialog(dlgParams);
                    cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            cancelDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog.cancel();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            postTransferCancelEvent(true);
                        }
                    });
                    cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            progressDialog.show();
                            cancelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Notice that the click listener changes to the standard View.OnClickListener.

Comment: The setButton() has to be BEFORE show() --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037433/how-to-set-cancel-button-in-progress-dialog

Comment: I am not using setButton but **getButton**. Look at the difference between my code and yours

Comment: Accepted answer. You need to call setButton() before, otherwise the `Button` doesn't show in the `Dialog`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, got it.:)

Comment: I actually already solved it by removing the line progressDialog.hide(), but I think you might be on point here. As it should probably not be expected to close the ProgressDialog on opening the Alert.

Comment: this setButton() is kind of confusing, from the Android docs: "Set a listener to be invoked when the **positive** button of the dialog is pressed." Yet the first param 'whichButton' is supposed to expect values "BUTTON_POSITIVE, BUTTON_NEGATIVE, or BUTTON_NEUTRAL" Also I would think this sets a Button, not Listener. Wouldn't be more correct to just use BUTTON_NEUTRAL with set text "Cancel" instead, in order to avoid that apparent default click behavior, that doesn't get overridden by the DialogInterface listener?

Comment: Not sure really. I used the specified technique from my post in some of my projects. I have not tried to use the neutral button. If you give it a try then can you post something about it.

Comment: Same thing with NEUTRAL.

Comment: Your solution works but I need to call setButton() before show(), with an empty DialogInterface.OnClick, otherwise, without calling setButton(), the Button simply isn't shown. Don't know why. However, I didn't like how it looked, the Alert over the Progress Dialog, so I chose to stick with just removing the line progressDialog.hide();, which does the job. The ProgressDialog is hidden but active, and shown again on dismissing the Alert with the progressDialog.show();